# Jquery to add row only for the clicked table button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, yii

Here is the case :

I'm using a jquery plug in to add rows in a table. The table has (+) button on the top side. If I click the (+) button, it will add 1 row to the table directly.
When I use 1 table in a page, it runs perfect. But if I use 2 or more tables, when I click (+) button, all the tables (not only the ones that I just clicked ) are also added 1 row. When I check the .js code to add the row:

```
var tabularInput = $(this);
$(settings.addInput).click(function(event) {
        if(settings.limit == 0 || tabularInput.find("tbody > tr").length < settings.limit) {
            if(settings.beforeAdd == null || settings.beforeAdd(tabularInput)) {
                var tbody = tabularInput.find("tbody");
                
                alert(tabularInput.id);
                
                var newRow = $(settings.rowTemplate).clone();
                tbody.append(newRow);
                
                newRow.find(":input").each(function() {
                    $(this)
                        .attr("id", $(this).attr("id").replace(/\___template__\_/, "_" + rowCount + "_"))
                        .attr("name", $(this).attr("name").replace(/\[__template__\]/, "[" + rowCount + "]"));
                });
                
                tabularInput.find(settings.removeInput).show();
                if(settings.limit != 0 && tabularInput.find("tbody > tr").length >= settings.limit) {
                    tabularInput.find(settings.addInput).hide();
                }
                
                rowCount++;
                if(settings.afterAdd) settings.afterAdd(tabularInput, newRow);
            }
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Ive added the alert(tabularInput.id) code to see the id, but it says undefined.
Now, here is the HTML table :

```
<table class="jtabularinput" id="yw0">
 <thead>
  <th>Nama Depan</th>
  <th>Nama Tengah</th>
  <th>Nama Belakang</th>
  <th><a class="input-add" title="Click to add a new row" href="#">Add</a></th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td><input name="Pengarang[0][nama_depan]" id="Pengarang_0_nama_depan" type="text" maxlength="16" /></td>
   <td><input name="Pengarang[0][nama_tengah]" id="Pengarang_0_nama_tengah" type="text" maxlength="16" /></td>
   <td><input name="Pengarang[0][nama_belakang]" id="Pengarang_0_nama_belakang" type="text" maxlength="16" /></td>
   <td style="text-align:center">
    <a class="input-remove" title="Click to remove this row" href="#">Remove</a>
   </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Anybody has the solution or insight where it goes wrong ? Thanks a lot

## EDITED

Found where the mistake is. I changed :

```
$(settings.addInput).click(function(event) {..}
```

to be :

```
tabularInput.find(settings.addInput).click(function(event) {..}
```

This way in will only take the corresponding table and add its row. Now it works perfect. Thanks all for the proposed solutions and your caring to help me solve the problem =)

Comment: a full example in a jsfiddle or something would be helpful. Also, you want to alert(tabularInput.attr('id'))

Comment: What is the scope of `var tabularInput = $(this);`? Is `this` a window object?

Comment: do you define the '+' button or does it create it? is the '+' button a child of the table or a sibling?

Comment: Im afraid that the code will be too long if i post it here. So here is the link to the .js code : http://www.gadgetcote.com/bangda/assets/f9520440/js/jquery.jtabularinput.js

Comment: @LukeSchafer I generate the code my self. As you can see in the above HTMl code, I place it inside the table  <a class="input-add" title="Click to add a new row" href="#">Add</a>

Comment: @LukeSchafer I've edited the alert code to be alert(tabularInput.attr('id')); and it pops up all the tabularinput object id in the page.

Comment: @liho1eye Sorry, I dont know exactly the var tabularInput = $(this); since Im still new to jquery and using plug ins

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are actually binding the plugin with your table?

Comment: @CalvinHiu you can remove that _var tabularInput = $(this);_ declaration and move it into the function, but don't just make it $(this) :)

Comment: @CalvinHiu http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring is a good place to start (eg: in a plugin "this" is already a jquery wrapped element).

Answer (score 0):

`tabularInput` is a jquery wrapped object, if you want its ID you will need to either ask jquery for it or drop to the dom element itself:

1)  `tabularInput.attr('id')`

2)  `tabularInput[0].id`

There are more than a few problems with this plugin, but you duplication is due to a misinterpretation of scope. You can't expect all those event handlers to remember some cached object you defined way up when the plugin was executed, unless you pass it into their closure as an argument.

Quick fix:

```
$(settings.addInput).click(function(event) {
    var tabularInput = $(this).closest('table');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(settings.addInput).click(function(event) {
    var tabularInput = $(this).closest('table.jtabularinput');
    // then the rest...
```

$(this) is the 'addInput' item (when called from within the click handler)

.closest finds the closest parent matching the selector, so in this case it's the table the element is in